# exceptions C++ , I just don't understand why the output is what it is

Tags: c++, arrays, oop, exception

```
#include <iostream>

 using namespace std;

class Array
{
    private:
      int* a;
      int n;
    public:
        Array(int n) : n(n) {a = new int[n];};
        ~Array(){delete a;};
        int& operator[](int i)
        {
            try
            {
                if ( i < 0 || i >= n) throw 1;
                return a[i];
            }
            catch(int i)
            {
                cout << "Exception Array" << endl;
                return a[0];
            } 
        };


};



int main()
{
    Array a(2);

    try
   {
      a[0] = 1;
      cout << "a[0]=" << a[0] << endl;
      a[1] = 1;
      cout << "a[1]=" << a[1] << endl;
      a[2] = 2;
      cout << "a[2]=" << a[2] << endl;
    }
catch(int i)
{
    cout << "Exception main " << endl;
}

cout << "End. " << endl;
}
```

Okay, so the output is this:

a[0]=1

a[1]=1

Exception Array

Exception Array

a[2]=2

End.

The thing that is confusing me is the reasoning why the program is returning
a[2] as value 2? Can someone go into more detail as to how this is achieved, step by step. I think I am not understanding something about exceptions in C++.

Comment: Why do you throw an exception and catch it immediately? You could say `return i < 0 || i >= n ? a[i] : a[0];`

Comment: I also don't see the point of throwing and catching in the same function. You should throw an exception to pass the error on up to the caller, if you handle it yourself you should just do some `if` check instead, not use exceptions which will cause overhead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
>  a[2] = 2;
> ```

Here you invoke your `operator[]` with an out-of-bounds value; it prints `Exception Array` and returns a reference to `a.a[0]`. As such (ignoring the log message), this assignment is equivalent to `a[0] = 2;` - the value of `a.a[0]` is now 2.

> ```
> cout << "a[2]=" << a[2] << endl;
> ```

Here you again invoke the `operator[]` with the same parameter; it again outputs the exception message and returns a reference to `a.a[0]` whose value is still 2, as assigned in the previous statement.

Answer (score 0):

This code

```
a[2] = 2;
cout << "a[2]=" << a[2] << endl;
```

tries to access `a[2]` twice, once in the assignment and once in the output statement. They are both out of range, so two exceptions.